# Find the probability of at most two accidents per day in total on these highways

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

this is a question in my textbook that doesn't have a solution. Any help on an answer would be great.

There are three highways in the county. Independently from one another, the
number of daily accidents that occur on these highways are Poisson random
variables with respective parameters $.3$, $.5$, and $.7$.

Find the probability of at most two accidents per day in total on these
highways.

*My attempt:*

let $X =$ number of accidents on each highway.

We want to find $P(X \leq 2) = P(X = 0, 1, 2) = P(X=0) +P(X= 1) + P(X=2)$

so $P(X=0) = (e^{-0.3})(e^{-0.5})(e^{-0.7})$

but I am having trouble finding $P(X = 1) $ and $P(X=2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $P(X=k)=\frac{(\lambda +\mu +\delta )^k}{k!}\cdot e^{-(\lambda +\mu +\delta)}$

$\lambda, \mu, \delta$ are the parameters. And k are the numbers of accidents in total on the three highways.

Comment: very helpful thank you!

Comment: @AlexChavez You are welcome.